# The inherited method execute query cannot be used in this subclass

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sybase

Copied some existing code that did an update, to perform a query.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt2  = connection.prepareStatement(sql);              
pstmt2.executeUpdate();
```

became

```
PreparedStatement pstmt2  = connection.prepareStatement(sql);              
pstmt2.executeQuery(sql);
```

When executing the code, received this exception.  I suspect this exception is only produced by sybase.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to experts-exchange for guidance - use the method createStatement not prepareStatement.

The SQL should be:
Statement pstmt2=dbconn2.createStatement();
ResultSet result = pstmt2.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: What version of Sybase? ASE, HANA?

Comment: This solution is vulnerable to SQL Injection. The one in the question looks safe. Well... if it worked.

Comment: @TheImpaler Performing `pstmt2.executeQuery(sql)` on a prepared statement is not allowed: JDBC 4.1 or higher compliant drivers should throw an exception. The OP should use `pstmt2.executeQuery()`

Comment: Thanks for the observations.  We are using ASE but I figured it would be a JDBC exception.  I wasn't sure because search results for the exception looked to be specific to Sybase.  The code is only used in test and, is testing an internal data feed so no concern there - a nice reminder though, that there is an alternative that must considered!

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the documentation of [`Statement.executeQuery(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-):

> **Throws**:
>     `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs, this
>   method is called on a closed `Statement`, the given SQL statement
>   produces a `ResultSet` object, **the method is called on a
>   `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`**

In other words, using `executeQuery(String)` (or any of the other `execute` methods accepting a String) is wrong, and should throw an exception in all JDBC compliant drivers. So Sybase throwing an exception here is correct and expected.

This requirement was introduced in JDBC 4.1 (Java 7), earlier the JDBC specification did not contain this requirement explicitly, and notably MySQL (and iirc MariaDB) Connector/J unfortunately still ignore this part of the specification.

You either should use

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    // set parameters
    try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
        // process result set
    }
}
```

or (if you're not using parameterized statements):

```
try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
    // process result set
}
```